# Elasticsearch Nested search with match

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got orders index, and It has nested structure like below;

```
{
  'baskets' => [
    {
      'id' => 123,
      'product' => {
        'title': 'blabla',
        'tags': [
          'value': 'Tag1',
          'value': 'Tag2'
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      'id' => 1234,
      'product' => {
        'title': 'blabla2',
        'tags': [
          'value': 'Tag3',
          'value': 'Tag2'
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make "similarity search" inside that informations like;

"Match inside tags, most match is the most closest. (For example If I search with Tag1, Tag2 It must be matched better"

But how can I make matching inside arrays in nested searchs?

I need to search like: where baskets.product.tags.value in ['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag4']

Better matching must be ordered first.

My search query is below. But not working well.

```
  ['bool' => 
    [
      'should' => [
        'nested' => [
          'path' => 'baskets.product.tags',
          'query' => ['terms' => ['baskets.product.tags' => $concept_array]]
          ]
        ],
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in ES are not exactly treated as arrays, more like multiple objects in the same field so you can't easily score on multiple matches. Maybe with a score script but it will be very brittle.

Instead you can add a new field to the `product`, like `all_tags`, type `text` (you might need to change the separator and tune analyzers if your tags can contain spaces) and put all your tags in there, it will be `"Tag1 Tag2"` and `"Tag3 Tag2"` in your example. Then a simple

```
"match": {"baskets.product.all_tags": "Tag3 Tag2"}
```

inside your `nested` query should do the trick, scoring higher docs with closely matching baskets.